# Calculating sub-regressions in R using by-function

Tags: r

I am currently working with the built-in data set "iris". I have calculated separate regressions for the three types of plant species like this and it worked:

```
reg1 = with(iris[iris$Species=="setosa",], lm(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length))

reg2 = with(iris[iris$Species=="versicolor",], lm(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length))

reg3 = with(iris[iris$Species=="virginica",], lm(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length))
```

Now, I am wondering if it is also possible to calculate three sub-regressions using the `by` function in R, and get similar output to the above.

I have tried it like this but I only receive error messages:

```
b <- by(iris, iris$Species, function(x){
  regby <- lm(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length)
}
```

Does anyone have any tips for me?

Comment: you forgot the right bracket

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code, however, still does not seem to work. 
There is no error message but whenever I type in "b" it says that object b was not found, so there is still an error in the code. 

Do you know why it does not work? Have I forgot to include something?